# How to code the output value in Haskell that equals a function?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that finds empty cells in a chess game I am making, and I want to replace one of my pieces into that empty spot that I found. I have a function for findCells, so I have a code something like this

```
movePawnBack :: GameState -> Player -> [[Cell]]
movePawnBack g p = if p == Black then BP = findCells g E else WP = findCells g E


findCells :: GameState -> Cell -> [(Int, Int)]
findCells b c = [(x, y) | x <- [0..4], y <-[0..4], getFromBoard (theBoard b) (x, y) == c]
```

However, it gives me an error that I don't have an `else` cause and if I do something like this `BP ==...` then I just return a boolean type which is not what I want. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: First, you should put a complete working example: What's a cell? What's GameState? With this code, is impossible to understand what's happening beside a type error on your function `movePawnBack`.

Comment: First of all you have a syntax error `BP = findCells g E` this is invalid, there is no assignment or mutation or whatever you are trying to do there. Secondly what is `E`, `WP`, `BP` and where did they come from?

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich, I don't think it's a syntax error, per se, but it's clearly a mistake. It means "calculate `findCells g E`, check if the result is `BP`, and if it's not, throw an error."

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think it means (or is intended to mean) that. After all, `BP` doesn't look at all like a `[(Int, Int)]`, which is the kind of thing `findCells` returns. But it's very unclear what it *is* intended to mean!

Comment: Ok I will put more code up. WK and BP are coming from a different module and E means Empty, So if I have an empty cell I want to fill it, so BP is now in the empty spot

Comment: The cells have coordinates x and y and are called BP WK or E for example

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are trying to do?

```
movePawnBack :: GameState -> Player -> (Cell -> [(Int, Int)])
movePawnBack g p = if p == Black then (findCells g) else (findCells g)
```

In order to return a function, besides currying, as it is done above, you can also use lambda

```
movePawnBack :: GameState -> Player -> (Cell -> [(Int, Int)])
movePawnBack g p = if p == Black then (\bp -> findCells g bp) else (\wp -> findCells g wp)
```

Also note the return type `(Cell -> [(Int, Int)])`, whenever it is in parenthesis, it usually means a function, although it is not required in above case, I put it there because of your question title: `output value in Haskell that equals a function?`. For instance map takes a function:

```
>>> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hello sorry was away. I am trying to replace the empty spot with a certain pawn, I will see if that works!